# what happens in linux glibc if keep increasingly accessing memory exceeding malloc() allocated size

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

Seems comments/answers just simply stops at C standard description, let's discuss a bit more deep with implementation specific.

I saw below code in other discussion:

```
struct { size_t x; char a[]; } *p;
p = malloc(sizeof *p + 100);
if (p)
{
    /* You can now access up to p->a[99] safely */
}
```

Then what if keep accessing p->a[i], 99< i < 0xffff or even bigger value?

1. malloc implementation should have a virtual memory block backed area for "(sizeof *p + 100)", so after "i" exceeds 100, initially it should be just corrupt data within the virtual memory block which might be non harmful.
2. if later "i" exceed that virtual memory block size, while next block is available and is never physical memory backed up(means ready to be allocated), would copy-on-write in kernel physical memory happens for next block on this bad access? And would malloc() later aware of this?
3. if next block is not in heap management, should p->a[i] get a virtual memory access violation error? Because malloc() is not called, so brk/sbrk won't be triggered to expand memory region of process heap.

Just curious how damage it is in this case...

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. The language will generally let you shoot yourself in the foot like this. Unchecked accesses are faster.

Comment: The answer to "what happens if I do [thing I'm not allowed to do]" in either C or C++ is usually that the program is allowed to do literally anything as a result.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed for being unclear.  Brett is specifically asking what behavior occurs in that case.

Comment: >>Undefined behavior is undefined.
maybe can think under certain lib implementation?

Comment: @Brett  *Just curious how damage it is in this case...* -- All of this research you're attempting to do can be thrown in the trash if the compiler implementation decides to do something different in a later version, or using different compiler options, etc.  So is it worth your time to chase the moving target called "undefined behavior"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, >>if the compiler implementation decides. You are correct. discuss under certain implementation is exactly what I hoped, maybe I should make more clear.

Comment: You're going to have to work around the SO community reluctance to discuss UB (which does have a decent reason). Maybe by making this an  x86 assembly question - it's still undefined, but maybe less frowned upon. x86 manuals don't go around warning you about stuff, they just assume you have better common sense (which says something about how high level language creators see their users...)

Comment: It's a pointless waste of time to discuss UB here.  It's a pointless waste of time to discuss some scenario that may be different on different machines. It's a pointless waste of time to discuss some scenario that may different at different times.  It's a pointless waste of time to discuss some scenario that may be different on different OS. Ditto compilers.  Ditto processors, Ditto MMU hardware. Etc.. etc.. etc..  If the OP wishes to explore what happens in its own environment, fine, but we cannot sensibly help with it.  It's a waste of time.  It is a time waster. It uses up time wastefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I try to access memory beyond a malloc()'d region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655971/what-happens-if-i-try-to-access-memory-beyond-a-mallocd-region)

Answer (score 6):

Accessing stuff outside of the allocated memory is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).   Anything can happen.  I hear nasal demons are a possibility.

[image: nasal demons]

If you are really lucky, you might get an access violation/segfault.  If you aren't lucky, then some other variable in the program may be overwritten, or nothing observable may happen, The moon may turn into the 7UP logo, or maybe something nasty squeezes out of your right nostril.

Comment: Not the downvoter. I like that [you do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444785/27678)

Comment: Gotta drive the point home somehow :)  Plus I commissioned and own the image.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but by sharing it on SO, you do not own it anymore [Legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

Comment: @AndyG:  He probably does still own it, but he has granted others rights to use it by virtue of posting it here and the licence that is required when doing so.

Comment: Yes let's vote him down over licensing! Yay Stack Overflow!

Comment: Those demons seem very happy, considering they've escaped from the seventh level of hell only to find themselves up the nose of a software developer.  I mean, just how unlucky can a demon get?

Comment: @alex  Generally they are promoted to Management.