# The purpose of union with only one member inside the struct

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linux-kernel, unions

I saw such union inside struct definition in pure [c](/questions/tagged/c) code in Linux kernel sources [`struct cma_multicast`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/drivers/infiniband/core/cma.c#L237) (it's not the only one place. Seems that it is some common practice):

```
struct cma_multicast {
    struct rdma_id_private *id_priv;
    union {
        struct ib_sa_multicast *ib;
    } multicast;
    struct list_head    list;
    void            *context;
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    struct kref     mcref;
};
```

But I can't figure out what is the purpose of union with only one member inside the struct? Why can't we just type `struct ib_sa_multicast *ib;` ?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066929/whats-the-purpose-of-using-a-union-with-only-one-member) but it has no usage explanation and has C++ specificity only.

**UPD:**
Posted example from Linux kernel instead of proprietary code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219214/discussion-on-question-by-budoattack-the-purpose-of-union-with-only-one-member-i).

Answer (score 2):

This says in this case multicast can have only one polymorphic dispatcher.

It is object oriented programming made in C. The union is kept only for uniformity of naming.