# Strange memory allocation in case of pointers using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
//    int a[1];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 876; ++i)
    a[i] = i;
printf("%d",a[799]);
}
```

Why is this code working, even if, I am allocating only 1 int's space using `malloc()`?

Comment: Its called UB(undefined behaviour). Anything could happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I try to access memory beyond a malloc()'d region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655971/what-happens-if-i-try-to-access-memory-beyond-a-mallocd-region)

Comment: @Karthick can it be a reason: malloc allocates a larger block of memory using sbrk() for avoiding future system calls.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why is this code working? Even if, I am allocating only 1 int's space using malloc ?* In such case answer in undefined behavior.

Allocating block of `4` bytes like

```
  int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); /* No need to cast the malloc result  */
```

and accessing beyond that like

```
a[i] = i; /* upto i<1 behavior is guaranteed as only 4byte allocated, not after */
```

results in **undefined behavior** i.e anything can happen and you shouldn't depend on it doing the same thing twice.

Side note, type casting the result of `malloc()` is not required as `malloc()` return type `void*` & its automatically promoted safely into required type. Read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
And always check the return value `malloc()`. for e.g

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
if( a != NULL) {
   /* allocated successfully & do_something()_with_malloced_memory() */ 
}
else {
    /* error handling.. malloc failed */ 
}
```

Comment: can it be a reason: malloc allocates a larger block of memory using sbrk() for avoiding future system calls.

Answer (score 2):

It *seems* to be working. There is absolutely **zero** guarantee it will work the same way after a recompile, or in a different environment.

Basically, here you're trying to access memory address, which is not allocated to your program (using any index other than `0`). So, from your program point of view, the memory address is *invalid*. Accessing invalid memory location invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, the behavior while accessing a memory region beyond what is allocated, is undefined. Run the same program on a system which is running memory intensive applications. You might see a SIGSEGV. Run your code through coverity static analysis and you will see it catching the buffer overrun.